# Do additional guest need to be present for hotel check in

Tags: legal, hotels, bookings

Do additional guest at hotels need to be present with you in the hotel when you check in? Or can I just register them as additional guests and let them check in at a later time?

My friend will be there with me on a Friday or Saturday. I need to be at the hotel on a Thursday for check in. As long as I register my name for the hotel and am paying for the room will it be acceptable to have them stay with me at hotel on Friday or Saturday as long as I tell the hotel and have my additional guest name down?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Can a hotel kick you out if you let an unregistered guest share a room with you?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22285/108) and [What is proper etiquette on bringing one night stands to a hotel room?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22293/108)

Answer (score 4):

In places where hotels are required to register their guests with the local authorities, they will ask for the ID of all guests. Hence all guests might not need to be present to check-in, but their ID's will. Other hotels might just ask for one ID. This is assuming that all guests begin their stay on the same night.

In your specific case you should not need the other person to be present, or their ID for that matter, since you will effectively be alone on the first night. You should of course explain to hotel staff that another person will be joining you for the remaining period of your stay, and again this should cause no problems. It is indeed a very common situation.