# Is it possible to share an individual hotel room?

Tags: legal, europe, hotels

I'm going to be living in a hotel in Germany for three weeks. I have booked and already payed an individual room for this time.

My girlfriend has just told me that she wants to come to visit me one weekend. We both are Spanish citizens (in case it matters) and we would like to share the room for this time. Is this common? How should I act? Should I send an email to the hotel asking if it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to play it safe, your best bet is to **ask the hotel**.  Maybe she can stay for free, maybe you need to pay a bit extra, maybe you need to switch to a double room for those few days -- it will depend on the hotel.

You can also just [try to bring her in](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22293/what-is-proper-etiquette-on-bringing-one-night-stands-to-a-hotel-room), and many larger hotels wouldn't even notice, but the longer the stay and the smaller the hotel, the higher the odds of being caught, and the [potential penalties are high](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22285/can-a-hotel-kick-you-out-if-you-let-an-unregistered-guest-share-a-room-with-you).

Answer (score 5):

**Definitely** contact the hotel and explain your situation. Particularly in Germany. Rules are expected to followed in Germany and it keeps things running efficiently and smoothly. You can always email them anonymously if you want to test the water and find out if it's possible to add her to the room.

Besides, most hotels are booked based on double occupancy and you are likely paying a single-person supplement anyhow. Does your room contain a double bed? Won't be a problem to add a guest. Is it a single bed ( doubtful )? If it is, I'm guessing it's a very small hotel... but many hotels can bring in a cot upon request.

That being said, many hotels in Europe are based on number of people, not number of beds.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest simply emailing the hotel and saying that the booking actually should be for two people, and that you trust they can update the booking.

See what they say.

If it's a guest house there might be an extra charge (at least to cover breakfast), for many hotels the price is the same for one person or two.

Comment: Other hotels might want to upgrade you to a double room, or demand a higher payment since you use the hotel facilities more. Do they have a swimming pool? A lounge? ...

Comment: @o.m. … but also buy fewer meals at the restaurant. It's actually quite common to have only double rooms *and charge extra for single occupancy*. So as Spehro wrote, anything's possible and in many cases it won't even cost extra.