# Proper etiquette to be able to bring sex worker in hotel room?

Tags: hotels, etiquette, sex

I plan to visit a European country where prostituion is legal. I will stay several days, visit the town during the day and have fun at night.

I have no idea how the normal proccess but, after reading [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/22303/57220) topic, I already have in mind to book a double bedroom. Besides that, are there things I can/have to do/check to avoid them to be blocked by the receptionnist? (I will book them online, I won't bring them personally from the street to the bedroom).

Comment: Book a room for 2 people in a large hotel, keep your activities quiet. That's it.

Comment: @JonathanReez what name does he (or she) use for the 2nd room? :)

Comment: Read the hotel rules and fine print, book using the option of two guest to a room that is if you don't plan to cycle a slew of partners. I am sure no hotel except  the lowest of roach motels would allow a convoy of partners parading to and from your room in the middle of the night. Alternatively depending on your funds and availability, perhaps you can book a room at a brothel for the whole night/day.

Comment: What European country are we talking about?

Comment: @GayotFow Register them is my main concern I think. UK and Romania

Comment: @GayotFow Mata Hari, of course

Comment: Please take into consideration that it is legal only when no coercion is involved, which is very often not the case.  http://www.gvnet.com/humantrafficking/Netherlands.htm

Comment: Most chain hotels could not even notice that your client was not a guest unless you took him or her to reception and pointed him out to the staff: they see five people walk past every minute. A family run place with six rooms might be different. A typical business hotel will neither know nor care.

Comment: This website, though it's based in Australia, not Europe, may be relevant for you. http://www.touchingbase.org/

Comment: I am very cynical: if your companion is blocked by the receptionist, it is only because she is in arrears on a kickback arrangement. She has been in your hotel before, and she is probably known by sight by receptionists and hotel security. That's probably a good thing, so that you aren't bringing in someone who wants to steal your kidneys. (Yeah, I know, urban legend.)

Comment: While prostitution is legal in several European countries, it is not socially accepted and there is no "proper etiquette" as far as the locals are concerned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have any experience with inviting sex workers to my hotel room, but I have plenty of experience with friends visiting me at a hotel (or vice-versa). Follow two simple rules and you'll be fine:

1. Book at a large hotel (50+ rooms). That way the receptionist won't care too much about who's coming and going, so your "friend" will be able to enter without any issues. One can even ask the reception for where the room is located and they'll happily show them where to go.
2. Book a room for two people. That way you're paying for two persons sharing the room at a given time so you're not cheating the hotel. If asked about the other person, say it's your girlfriend who's coming later on.

As long as you don't invite women who look like they're in the final stages of a methamphetamine addiction it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Can they for me give to give a registration name for her? (As suggested by @GayotFow)

Comment: @QuietSteps sure, in that case make something up. As long as you pay for 2 people it should be fine. It's the small hotels that can be picky about stuff like that, avoid them.

Answer (score 10):

Strangely enough, using different keywords when searching for this topic gave different results. Searching for "sex worker hotel" gave results such as [Qld laws ban sex workers from hotels, motels](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2012-11-02/qld-laws-ban-sex-workers-from-hotels-motels/4350522), about hotels in Queensland, Australia (not a jurisdiction you're asking about) being allowed to ban sex workers. However, searching for "escort hotel" gave results such as [How to Pick an Escort-Friendly Hotel](http://www.modelsescortagency.com.au/pick-escort-friendly-hotel/) and [The Hotel Experience](http://scarletblue.com.au/hotels).

They suggest letting the agency choose the hotel, but that may be less applicable in your case since you're staying for several days, not just a single night.

Another detail they mention is how to avoid being blocked by the receptionist. It suggests avoiding hotels that require guests to be signed in, or have a keycard to access the elevators, and if a hotel shuts down at night, be able to buzz a guest in directly, rather than checking in with a night clerk.